# Running gcloud command with help of python in bitbucket pipeline but it is failing?

Tags: python, shell, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

I have created a python file which has the gcloud `add-tag` command, it is executed in bitbucket pipeline but falling to execute completely.

```
import os,sys,subprocess
```

A different gcloud command is producing the expected output:

```
os.system("gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION} --project {PROJECT}")
```

First try, producing no output:

```
os.system('gcloud container images add-tag gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION} gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION}:latest')
```

Second try, producing the expected output:

```
os.system(f'bin/bash -c "gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION} --project {PROJECT_ID_DEVOPS}"')
```

Producing no output:

```
os.system(f'bin/bash -c "gcloud container images add-tag gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION} gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION}:latest")
```

Third try, the following error is appearing. This same command structure is used for `gcloud builds submit` commands and it created a new image but is failing to add the tag. I have tried with `shell=True` but it is getting nowhere.

Getting expected output:

```
subprocess.run(['gcloud', 'builds', 'submit', '--tag', f'gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION}', '--project', f'{PROJECT}'])
```

No output:

```
subprocess.run(['gcloud', 'container', 'images', 'add-tag', f'gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION}', f'gcr.io/{PROJECT}/test:{VERSION}:latest','--project', f'{PROJECT}'])
```

Error message for third `add-tag` command:

```
File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 488, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:

File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__

    restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child

    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gcloud': 'gcloud'
```

Comment: I don’t see any error with the commands themselves, but it would be good if you show your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, since it shows the exact steps of your build. This error could be caused due to the location of the CloudSDK files as shown [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Problems-with-gcloud-command/qaq-p/740620). Additionally, using the [Cloud Build](https://github.com/googleapis/python-cloudbuild) API client for Python could be an alternative.

Comment: @ErnestoContrerasPinon You are right about origin of error! Commnds did not cause issue. I have tried to use combine command because apparently  if we use seperate command then it failed to detect first command output and then failing add-tag command ! But now second command is failing in pipeline, because it is not detecting destination part in add-tag command in pipeline(maybe breaking  command in pipeline) `ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.add-tag) argument DEST_IMAGE [DEST_IMAGE ...]: Must be specified.
/bin/bash: line 2: gcr.io/project_name/image_name:latest: No such file or directory`

Comment: @ErnestoContrerasPinon @DazWilkin `proc = subprocess.Popen(f'{cmd1} ; {cmd2}', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
 
 try:
 
     outs, errs = proc.communicate()
 
 except TimeoutExpired:
 
     proc.kill()
 
     outs, errs = proc.communicate()` where cmd1 is build submit command & cmd2 is add-tag command ! And I am using simple dockerfile! It is still not clear that why add-tag command is breaking in pipeline!

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`gcloud images add-tag`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/add-tag) incorrectly.

The syntax has the form:

```sh
gcloud container images add-tag \
  gcr.io/myproject/myimage:mytag1 \
  gcr.io/myproject/myimage:mytag2
```

Your highlight one important issue with using e.g. Python to invoke a processes, it's very difficult to capture errors effectively.

I second @ernesto-contreras-pinon comment that you should consider using the [Cloud Build SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/python-cloudbuild) to build a client directly.

I advise you to **only** use `os.subprocess` when there is **no** other alternative to executing a binary **or** when you're testing a binary.